# In xsl tokenize, how to get the preceding text value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest, how to get the preceding text within tokenize. In this sample, based preceded text web attribute is to be applied. Example if 'SKY1996' type text preceded by string 'Moon', then attribute value is 'Moon', otherwise 'Sun'.

**XML:**

```
<article>
 <text1>The solar eclipse Sun: SKY1996 is happenned in 1996</text1>
 <text2>The moon eclipse Moon: SKY1997 is happenned in 1997</text2>
</article>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text1/text()|text2/text()">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' ')">
            <xsl:variable name="varPrecededText"><xsl:value-of select=".[preceding-sibling::node()[1]]"/></xsl:variable><!--Within tokenize, preceded text value --><!--Requesting suggestion to get this -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="matches(., '^([S][K][Y])\d{4}$')">
                    <xsl:element name="web">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="contains($varPrecededText, 'Moon')">
                                    <xsl:text>MoonEclipse:</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>SunEclipse:</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element><xsl:if test="not(position()=last())"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<article>
<text1>The solar eclipse Sun: <web href="SunEclipse:SKY1996">SKY1996</web> is happenned in 1996</text1>
<text2>The moon eclipse Moon: <web href="MoonEclipse:SKY1997">SKY1997</web> is happenned in 1997</text2>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use analyze-string:

```
<xsl:template match="text1/text()|text2/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="((\w+):)\s+([S][K][Y]\d{{4}})">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <web href="{regex-group(2)}Eclipse:{regex-group(3)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
            </web>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

`((\w+):)\s+([S][K][Y]\d{{4}})` captures `Sun: SKY1996` and `Moon: SKY1997`, `Sun` and `Moon` in group 2, `SKY1996` and `SKY1997` in group 3. These matches are handled in *xsl:matching-substring* to replace them with the desired structure. Non-matches are kept as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion sir, plus one.